# get variable which inside of a def and a class, tensorflow 1.14 using Jupiter

Tags: python, numpy, printing

I am using a class, and I want to print the shape of  Yproj and Xproj, which are inside of a def.
I am using return, but maybe I am not doing right

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__build_flag = -1
        self.__train_flag = -1

    def build(self, dim, ddim, hdim, num_layers=3, 
              activation=tf.nn.tanh, init_lr=1e-5):
        """ Build tensorflow model """

        # Parameters
        self.__random_state = random_state  
            
        # Loss function definition

        Sx, Ux , Vx =tf.linalg.svd(self.__psiNNx, full_matrices=False, compute_uv=True)

        # # Project X and Y onto  Principal components
        Yproj=tf.matmul(tf.transpose(Ux), self.__psiNNy)
        Xproj=tf.matmul(tf.transpose(Ux), self.__psiNNx)

        # Build complete
        print("Built tensorflow graph.")
        self.__build_flag = 0
```

My idea is:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):

    def build(self, dim, ddim, hdim, num_layers=3, 
              activation=tf.nn.tanh, init_lr=1e-5):
        """ Build tensorflow model """

        bla bla bla 

        return Xproj, Yproj
```

Comment: Your idea of `return Xproj, Yproj` seems exactly right. What seems wrong to you?

Comment: I get this error : <bound method test.build of < file.test object at 0x7fa97862d208>>
In [270]: